# Java Socket sending command to AV receiver over IP

Tags: java, android, sockets, hex, bytecode

Hey all I am having an issue with trying to figure out why this code does not work. it never errors - it just doesn't do anything. I checked with my Onkyo iPhone app and it works and I'm using the same config as it is.

Here is the main code that sets up the command:

```
public StringBuilder getEiscpMessage(String command) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int eiscpDataSize = 2 + command.length() + 1; // this is the eISCP data size

    sb.append("ISCP");

    // the following are all in HEX representing one char
    // 4 char Big Endian Header
    sb.append((char) 0x00);
    sb.append((char) 0x00);
    sb.append((char) 0x00);
    sb.append((char) 0x10);

    // 4 char  Big Endian data size
    sb.append((char) ((eiscpDataSize >> 24) & 0xFF));
    sb.append((char) ((eiscpDataSize >> 16) & 0xFF));
    sb.append((char) ((eiscpDataSize >> 8) & 0xFF));
    sb.append((char) (eiscpDataSize & 0xFF));

    // eiscp_version = "01";
    sb.append((char) 0x01);

    // 3 chars reserved = "00"+"00"+"00";
    sb.append((char) 0x00);
    sb.append((char) 0x00);
    sb.append((char) 0x00);

    //  eISCP data
    // Start Character
    sb.append("!");

    // eISCP data - unittype char '1' is receiver
    sb.append("1");

    // eISCP data - 3 char command and param    ie PWR01
    sb.append(command);

    // msg end - EOF
    //sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt("0D", 16));
    sb.append((char) 0x0D);

    System.out.println("eISCP data size: " + eiscpDataSize + "(0x" + Integer.toHexString(eiscpDataSize) + ") chars");
    System.out.println("eISCP msg size: " + sb.length() + "(0x" + Integer.toHexString(sb.length()) + ") chars");

    return sb;
}

public void sendCommand(String command, boolean closeSocket) {
    StringBuilder sb = getEiscpMessage(command);

    if (connectSocket()) {
        try {
            System.out.println("sending " + sb.length() + " chars: ");
            convertStringToHex(sb.toString(), true);

            out_.writeBytes(sb.toString());
            out_.flush();
            System.out.println("sent!");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (closeSocket) closeSocket();
}

public static String convertStringToHex(String str, boolean dumpOut) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    String out_put = "";

    if (dumpOut) System.out.println("Ascii: " + str);
    if (dumpOut) System.out.print("Hex: ");

    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        out_put = Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]);
        if (out_put.length() == 1) hex.append("0");
        hex.append(out_put);

        if (dumpOut)
            System.out.print("0x" + (out_put.length() == 1 ? "0" : "") + out_put + " ");
    }

    if (dumpOut) System.out.println("");

    return hex.toString();
}
```

The output its sending looks like this:

> ISCP������������������!1QSTN

And according to the documentation it looks right to me?
[image]

And the rest of the System.out.printLn is this:

> eISCP data size: 7(0x7) chars
>
> eISCP msg size: 23(0x17) chars
>
> Connected to 192.168.1.33 on port 60128
>
> out_Init
>
> inInit
>
> sending 23 chars:
>
> Ascii: ISCP??????????????????!1PWRQSTN
>
> Hex: 0x49 0x53 0x43 0x50 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x21 0x31 0x51 0x53 0x54 0x4e 0x0d
>
> sent!

Here is the [full source code](https://pastebin.com/xWhTWpB8) to the java app.

It would be great if someone who knows java sockets and byte code better than I jump in and help me out! Maybe there's just something I am missing or incorrectly inserting? :o)

[image]

Comment: Just tell in hex what you send. Then tell in hex what you receive.

Comment: You cannot use StringBuilder and String class if you wanna send byte commands.

Comment: @blackapps It looks like its already converting the string to byte? `out_.writeBytes(sb.toString());`

Comment: Use an `ByteArrayOutputStream` or a `ByteBuffer` for building a byte array you can send.

Comment: Converting a sting to byte is wrong as you should not use a string to collect bytes to begin with. Put your bytes in a byte array or maybe even better write them directly to the output stream. Why would you buffer them?